# Where can I find a reliable resource that compares different providers of Microsoft VPS and Dedicated Servers?

Tags: vps, web-hosting, dedicated-server

Where can I find a reliable resource that compares different providers of Microsoft VPS and Dedicated Servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the provisers of VPS and dedicated server and many other server providers [here](http://www.comparewebresellers.com/)